# How to understand this `when they connect are not special` sentence?

Tags: meaning

From [this doc](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> The individual rooms assigned to clients when they connect are not special in any way

I am not understand this `when they connect are not special` sentence.

What's the meaning of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that document:

> **Room**: The recipient of the message. This can be set to the session ID of a client to address that client’s room, or to any custom room created by the application, If this argument is omitted the event is broadcasted to all connected clients.

Now I know the `individual room` is the client's own, every client have one. `they connect are not special` means they do not in a application created room.

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* group together "when they connect are not special".

It's the individual **rooms** that are not special. These rooms are assigned to clients when they connect.

What it all means would require the whole of this text to be read by a programmer.

Comment: whats meaning of ‘special’ there? does it mean the conected

Comment: @aircraft Listen, to give an answer to this question requires someone to read this whole thing and be proficient in programming. I'm not even sure the words "room" and "client" aren't abstractions here. The sense here is very much contingent on the context, and I'm not a programmer and don't understand the context. Normally, "a special X" means "different from other Xs in some aspect." So, here, all "rooms" are the same and are not treated any differently from one another.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting the sentence as a plain English sentence.

The sentence parses better when broken up this way:

- The (((individual rooms) assigned to clients) when they connect) are not special in any way.

The word "they" refers to the clients (the clients connect). The *individual rooms* aren't special.

This means that when clients connect and rooms are allocated to them, the rooms are just ordinary rooms; they (the rooms) are not special rooms.

Comment: Whats the `special rooms` means in there? and the `individual rooms` means what?

Answer (score 0):

**when they connect are not special** is not proper grouping. It is like this:

> The rooms
>
> - individual
> - assigned
>
>   - to clients
>   - when they connect
> - are not special in any way